# Jonathan sinned against Saul not God

Tags: sin, death

In 1 Samuel 14 why was Jonathan’s action of eating the honey when he was unaware of his fathers command, more of a sin than the Israelites eating meat with blood?

Comment: Welcome to BHSE.  Thanks for your contribution.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: I think that is the point of the story - Saul was becoming increasingly irrational as evidenced by his erratic behavior.  He would soon lose his mind.

Answer (score 0):

1 Samuel 14:44-45 NIV

> <sup>**44**</sup> Saul said, “May God deal with me, be it ever so severely, if you do not die, Jonathan.”
>
> <sup>**45**</sup> But the men said to Saul, “Should Jonathan die—he who has brought about this great deliverance in Israel? Never! As surely as the Lord lives, not a hair of his head will fall to the ground, for he did this today with God’s help.” **So the men rescued Jonathan, and he was not put to death.**

Whose judgment determined Jonathan's supposed guilt? The intervention of the Lord ultimately spared Jonathan through the men, proving his innocence to the Lord. This indicated that Saul became reckless after Samuel rebuked him in Gilgal (1 Samuel 13:11-14), and when Samuel announced the Lord's judgment;

1 Samuel 13:14 NIV

> But now your kingdom will not endure; the Lord has sought out a man after his own heart and appointed him ruler of his people, because you have not kept the Lord’s command.

Answer (score 0):

The internal logic of the story as a whole implies that Jonathan DID sin against God.

In v37 Saul makes an inquiry of God (presumably through Urim and Thummim) about the next step to take. But God refuses to answer. That refusal justifies Saul's conclusion in the next verse, that God is offended by some sin that Israel has committed.

In vv40-42 Saul makes inquiry of God, through Urim and Thummim, to find out the culprit who has offended God. The answer, provided by God himself in the usual way, is that Jonathan is the culprit. If we assert that Jonathan was innocent, we are arguing with God.

The rationale of Jonathan's guilt would be that in v24 Saul "laid an oath on the people", meaning that God accepted Saul as the spokesman for the people as a whole. Therefore the oath was binding on the whole people in the eyes of God. Knowing the story of Job, we should be wary of arguing with God about whether or not he is acting justly. If God says that Jonathan sinned, then he sinned.

If Jonathan sinned, then releasing him from the death penalty was an act of disobedience on Saul's part. And that sets up a sequence of THREE successive acts of disobedience. The premature sacrifice at Gilgal (ch13), in which Saul was giving way to the impatient will of his people instead of leading them into obedience. The release of Jonathan, in which Saul was giving way to the sympathetic will of his people instead of leading them into obedience. The sparing of the Amalekite herds and flocks (ch15), in which Saul was giving way to the greedy will of his people (sacrifice = massive celebratory feast) instead of leading them into obedience. There is a pattern here which explains overall why Saul had to go.